# How to refactor this?

Tags: c#, reflection, code-snippets

I was trying to refactor this

```
class AClass
{
     string Property1 { get; set; }
     string Property2 { get; set; }
     string Property3 { get; set; }

     void AMethod(AClass other)
     {
         if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Property1))
         {
              this.Property1 = other.Property1;
         }

         if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Property2))
         {
              this.Property2 = other.Property2;
         }

         if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Property3))
         {
              this.Property3 = other.Property3;
         }
     }
 }
```

And the only thing I could come up was

```
    private string GetFirstNotNullOrEmpty(string first, string second)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(first))
        {
            return second;
        }

        return first;
    }
```

and

```
    this.Property1 = GetFirstNotNullOrEmpty(this.Property1, other.Property1);
```

Which is not exactly equivalent, but will do the job. Is there a better way to refactor this?

Comment: [For future reference](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I added some reflection code to handle N properties. Let us know how this goes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to do this for the N string properties of that class, you should implement that using [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

**Update**

It's all about "teh codez", right? Here it goes:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public string Property0 { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
    public string Property4 { get; set; }
    public string Property5 { get; set; }
    public string Property6 { get; set; }
    public string Property7 { get; set; }
    public string Property8 { get; set; }
    public string Property9 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //just to print out all properties and values
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(SomeClass).GetProperties())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + "," + prop.PropertyType + " = " + prop.GetValue(this, null));
        }
        return base.ToString();
    }

    public void CopyStringPropertiesIfEmptyFrom(SomeClass SourceInstance)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(SomeClass).GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(System.String) && String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)prop.GetValue(this, null)))
            {
                prop.SetValue(this, prop.GetValue(SourceInstance, null), null);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: By using reflection you can even designate an attribute to tell if a string property is "copiable" or not. How would it be fragile?

Comment: o: I'm sorry, I didn't think it through. You don't have to use magic strings to do this. A call to `this.GetType().GetProperties()` would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a method you could collapse the ifs into ternary operators:

```
this.Property1 = String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Property1)? other.Property1 : this.Property1;
```

Answer (score 1):

implement the check in the properties themselves.

```
public class AClass
{
    string Property1 
    { 
        get { return _Property1; }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_Property1))
            {
                _Property1 = value
            }
        }
    }
    private string _Property1;


    void AMethod(AClass other)
    {
        this.Property1 = other.Property1;// Property can only be set once.
    }

}
```

Comment: That's not refactoring, the code replication level is the same.

Comment: not true. for instance if you have two or three methods that do this, Then you would implement them as if the Null check did not exist. however if you stay with the original method then you have to copy the null check over and over.

Comment: because you now have the code on the properties... rather then in the function. The hold the "only change if null" trait wherever they go. For instance, rather then passing the other class into the AMethod method. You could just set the properties you want to transfer over (if the property is null) and those properties would transfer. (if the property is null) I guess it is probably not accomplishing your task because I dont know what your task is. Your code example made very little sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of using Reflection when I can avoid it, so I actually like your suggested option in the question, but mixed with Tesserex's answer slightly:

```
private string GetFirstNotNullOrEmpty(string first, string second)
{
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(first)) ? second : first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be something like

```
private void SetFirstNotNullOrEmpty(string first, string second, Action<T> setter)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(first))
    {
        setter(second);
    }
}
```

and it would be called like this:

```
this.Property1 = GetFirstNotNullOrEmpty(this.Property1, other.Property1, i => this.Property1 = i);
```

This would be nicer if those weren't C# properties. With public fields I could pass the reference and have both the getter and the setter in a single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that needs to be refactored here is unintuitive names such as Property1 and AClass. Use meaningful names for class and property names so that they reflect the intent clearly.

Probably, the OP wants us to focus on the problem in hand and not on this aspect.