# Efficient way of updating a collection from another collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, observablecollection

Is the following way of updating an `ObservableCollection` from another one (both based on the same class) good enough or it better to be done in another way (or just to be improved)?

```
foreach (MyEntity c in collection2)
    {
       collection1.Where(p => p.EntID == c.EntID).FirstOrDefault().Field1 = c.Field1;
       collection1.Where(p => p.EntID == c.EntID).FirstOrDefault().Field2 = c.Field2;
       ...
       collection1.Where(p => p.EntID == c.EntID).FirstOrDefault().FieldN = c.FieldN;         
    }
```

`EntID` is the primary key.
*(Under good enough I mean fast and efficient).*

Comment: Do you need to add items that are new in collection2 to collection1? What about removing items that are not in collection 2 but are in collection1? These complicate the solution a little bit, but are not that difficult.

Comment: @CMP Thanks. Yes, in the end I need to do all that you mentioned. Just wanted to make example simpler to get the essence of the approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   var myItem = collection1.Where(p => p.EntID == c.EntID).FirstOrDefault();
   if (myItem == null)
       continue;
   myItem.Field1 = c.Field1;
   myItem.Field2 = c.Field2;
   ...
   myItem.FieldN = c.FieldN;
```

If `myItem` and `c` are different types, have a look at AutoMapper.

Comment: Looks much nicer, and saves quite a bit by not looking up the item for every property. The null check also avoids a potential crash bug.

Answer (score 2):

As a complementary answer, you can use reflection to copy the N fields from one object to another. I've already talked about this here: [How to refactor this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653995/how-to-refactor-this) .

You can have your class (SomeClass) implement this code (both objects are the same class):

```
public void CopyPropertiesFrom(SomeClass SourceInstance)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(SomeClass).GetProperties())
        prop.SetValue(this, prop.GetValue(SourceInstance, null), null);
}
```

That way, if your class has new properties, you don't have to bother updating the code, it's already there!

For objects with different class, that's also doable via reflection by the property name, but there are some assumptions you have to make (what if property does not exist, what property is different type, what is property value is null, etc.)

Comment: Yes, it is. And should be used with wisdom. If he's copying a 100 hundred objects, it's imperceptible (1-2 ms more). For 1000, takes about 30-40 ms more. For 10.000, 300-350 ms more, eyebrows raise.  It only starts stinking above 100.000. So, use cautiously.

Obs.: Data from benchmark app.