# How to create a List<unknown type at compile time> and copy items via System.Reflection.PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, list, reflection, types

I have come across something pretty complex. I would be obliged if anyone can help.

1) I have to create a List<> of unknown type at compile time. That I have already achieved.

```
 Type customList = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(tempType);
 object objectList = (List<object>)Activator.CreateInstance(customList);
```

"temptype" is the custom type thats been already fetched.

2) Now I have `PropertyInfo` object which is that list from which I have to copy all items to the the instance that I have just created "objectList"

3) Then I need to iterate and access the items of "objectList" as if it were a "System.Generic.List".

Cutting long story short, using reflection I need to extract a property that is a list and have it as an instance for further use. Your suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Umair

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, but when you find yourself trying to make a List<> of unknown types, often times the answer is a non-generic List instead.

Comment: Do you have any information about the type that will be bound to the list in the constructed type?   It is possible to constrain generics to a value or reference type or even to ensure that it satisfies a number of interfaces.    I don't have it ready at hand, but chapter 3 of John Skeet's "C# in Depth" does a deep dive on this topic.

Comment: I think you need to not cut a long story short, and instead give rather more detail. Some more code showing what you have already would definitely help.

Comment: @Omayr, Your code does fail when executed due to casting to different type... If you show your goal as couple lines of code someone may be able to help you better. So far it is unclear what you have trouble with...

Comment: @ Charlie: could you be more specific about non-generic list. Like how do I go about it.

Comment: @ Alexei Levenkov: As I mentioned that I need to dig out a list<unknown type> (Property/PropertyInfo) of an Object lets say "X" via reflection. Except the Type of object "X" nothing is known at compile time. And I need an object (List<unknown type>) that needs to be an exact replica of the respected (Property/PropertyInfo) of object "X". So that i can access the items of the list. I hope I am clear now. Your suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many of the .NET generic collection classes also implement their non-generic interfaces. I'd make use of these to write your code.

```
// Create a List<> of unknown type at compile time.
Type customList = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(tempType);
IList objectList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(customList);

// Copy items from a PropertyInfo list to the object just created
object o = objectThatContainsListToCopyFrom;
PropertyInfo p = o.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName");
IEnumerable copyFrom = p.GetValue(o, null);
foreach(object item in copyFrom) objectList.Add(item); // Will throw exceptions if the types don't match.

// Iterate and access the items of "objectList"
// (objectList declared above as non-generic IEnumerable)
foreach(object item in objectList) { Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString()); }
```

Comment: I am not able to declare an IList like you have declared it. Thats probably because I am using 3.5 framework.

Comment: Be sure to have `using System.Collections;` in addition to `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Answer (score 0):

Do you think this would help you? [Efficient way of updating a collection from another collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747113/efficient-way-of-updating-a-collection-from-another-collection/5747468#5747468)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something similar. I borrowed the `SetProperties()` method from [NullSkull](http://www.nullskull.com/faq/166/use-net-reflection-to-copy-matching-class-properties-from-on-object-type-to-another.aspx) and wrote a simple method that calls the NullSkull `SetProperties()`:

```
    public static List<U> CopyList<T, U>(List<T> fromList, List<U> toList)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] fromFields = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo[] toFields = typeof(U).GetProperties();
        fromList.ForEach(fromobj =>
        {
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(U));
            Util.SetProperties(fromFields, toFields, fromobj, obj);
            toList.Add((U)obj);
        });

        return toList;
    }
```

...so with one line of code I can retrieve a `List<desired class>` populated with matching values by name from `List<source class>` as follows:

```
List<desired class> des = CopyList(source_list, new List<desired class>());
```

As far as performance goes, I didn't test it, as my requirements call for small lists.